# Column-wise rolling mean in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a large dataset (in wide format) with millions of rows and 15 columns (time-series features).

I want to calculate the moving average for each observation. I can do that with the code block below. However, it requires converting the data frame into a long format. However, I think that this (converting wide to long and vice versa) will be inefficient as the dataset grows. Also, I need to deal with `.groupby()`.

Can I calculate rolling mean in a column-wise manner?

Please find the minimum reproducible example of the current methodology attached below.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': range(3), 
                   'Date_1': range(3, 6), 
                   'Date_2': range(4, 7), 
                   'Date_3': range(5, 8),
                   'Date_4': range(6, 9),
                   'Date_5': range(11, 14)})
```

```
df
   id  Date_1  Date_2  Date_3  Date_4  Date_5
0   0       3       4       5       6      11
1   1       4       5       6       7      12
2   2       5       6       7       8      13
```

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars= "id")
df = df.sort_values(["id", "variable"])
```

```
df
    id variable  value
0    0   Date_1      3
3    0   Date_2      4
6    0   Date_3      5
9    0   Date_4      6
12   0   Date_5     11
1    1   Date_1      4
4    1   Date_2      5
7    1   Date_3      6
10   1   Date_4      7
13   1   Date_5     12
2    2   Date_1      5
5    2   Date_2      6
8    2   Date_3      7
11   2   Date_4      8
14   2   Date_5     13
```

```
df["ma"] = df.groupby("id")["value"].rolling(3).mean().values
    id variable  value        ma
0    0   Date_1      3       NaN
3    0   Date_2      4       NaN
6    0   Date_3      5  4.000000
9    0   Date_4      6  5.000000
12   0   Date_5     11  7.333333
1    1   Date_1      4       NaN
4    1   Date_2      5       NaN
7    1   Date_3      6  5.000000
10   1   Date_4      7  6.000000
13   1   Date_5     12  8.333333
2    2   Date_1      5       NaN
5    2   Date_2      6       NaN
8    2   Date_3      7  6.000000
11   2   Date_4      8  7.000000
14   2   Date_5     13  9.333333
```

The desired output is below. The NaN columns can be dropped but that is not significant for now.

```
df[["id", "variable", "ma"]].pivot("id", columns = "variable", 
values = "ma")
variable  Date_1  Date_2  Date_3  Date_4    Date_5
id                                                
0            NaN     NaN     4.0     5.0  7.333333
1            NaN     NaN     5.0     6.0  8.333333
2            NaN     NaN     6.0     7.0  9.333333
```

Edit: Thank you @Mortz and @PanagiotisKanavo for prompts
Thank you

Comment: The most efficient way would be to have one Series per "thing" that gets measured. Pandas is optimized for series operations. If you have eg 15 stock symbols and 1M observations for each, the most efficient way would be to have 15 series. You can convert from wide to long form using [wide_to_long](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) or [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos, thank you. But this also requires subsetting the dataset based on `id`, then converting them into the long format, using `df.rolling().mean()`, then converting them into the wide format, and merging. Right? Why this is more efficient than the current way i.e. converting long format and then  `df.groupby().rolling().mean()`?

Also, the number of "thing" will be very high as wel..

Comment: A minimal, reproducible example would be good here - with the expected output

Comment: Are you saying `new_col_0 = col_0 / 1`, `new_col_1 = (col_0 + col_1) / 2`, `new_col_2 = (col_0 + col_1 + col_2) / 3 ` and so on... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rolling` method takes in an `axis` parameter, which you can set to 1 -

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': range(3), 
                   'Date_1': range(3, 6), 
                   'Date_2': range(4, 7), 
                   'Date_3': range(5, 8),
                   'Date_4': range(6, 9),
                   'Date_5': range(11, 14)})

df = df.set_index('id')
df.rolling(3, axis=1).mean()
```

```
    Date_1  Date_2  Date_3  Date_4    Date_5
id                                          
0      NaN     NaN     4.0     5.0  7.333333
1      NaN     NaN     5.0     6.0  8.333333
2      NaN     NaN     6.0     7.0  9.333333
```